# How do I determine if another party has filed me for bankruptcy in Australia?

Tags: australia, bankruptcy

I understand here in Australia, company can file for bankruptcy on your behalf or without you even knowing if you owe them money over $5000.

How do I do a “free” search on the bankruptcy site. I need to know if I’m already included there.

Comment: *without you even knowing* - highly unlikely that you are unaware if you owe someone $5,000+. Filing you for bankruptcy means the creditor may never see their cash again, so they will try to collect the money many times before they file you for bankruptcy.

Comment: @ssn not knowing that you owe them is one thing, them filing for a debt that you don't owe (fraudulently) is quite another.

Answer (score 3):

I doubt there is a free search available. [The paid search with the Australian Financial Security Authority costs $15.](https://services.afsa.gov.au/brs/search)